# Udev SYMLINK rule is not working!

Tags: kernel, udev

im trying to create a udev symlink rule:

Here is what i have written so far which doesnt seem to work:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTR{size}=="60626944", ATTRS{model}=="USB DISK 2.0    ", SYMLINK+="integralusb"
```

The device i am trying to create a SYMlink on upon plugging in is a USB thumb-drive. Here is the output of **udevadm info --query=all /dev/sdb**

```
 udevadm info --query=all /dev/sdb
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb
N: sdb
L: 0
S: disk/by-id/usb-_USB_DISK_2.0_900074BF37B00367-0:0
S: disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:10.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:10.0/usb2/2-3/2-3:1.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb
E: DEVNAME=/dev/sdb
E: DEVTYPE=disk
E: MAJOR=8
E: MINOR=16
E: SUBSYSTEM=block
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=5783303806
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=26bd
E: ID_MODEL=USB_DISK_2.0
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20DISK\x202.0\x20\x20\x20\x20
E: ID_MODEL_ID=9917
E: ID_REVISION=PMAP
E: ID_SERIAL=_USB_DISK_2.0_900074BF37B00367-0:0
E: ID_SERIAL_SHORT=900074BF37B00367
E: ID_TYPE=disk
E: ID_INSTANCE=0:0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:080650:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usb-storage
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:10.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_10_0-usb-0_3_1_0-scsi-0_0_0_0
E: ID_PART_TABLE_TYPE=dos
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/disk/by-id/usb-_USB_DISK_2.0_900074BF37B00367-0:0 /dev/disk/by-path/pci-0000:00:10.0-usb-0:3:1.0-scsi-0:0:0:0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
```

I have no idea what i have done wrong, i am new to creating udev rules but this looks okay to me.

Comment: It looks like you used something like `udevadm info --attribute-walk /dev/sdb` to extract the matching part of your _udev_ rule. If not, please check if there are any inadvertant typos. If you debug your rule e.g. by replacing the `SYMLINK` directive with something like `RUN="/usr/bin/touch /tmp/rule_processed.txt"`, do you see that this temporary file is created when you add the device?

Comment: Or `udevadm info -a /dev/sdb`, this shows `ATTR{size}=="468862128"` for me, with sda. To debug also use "udevadm monitor ...". (I found my RUNs only failed in journalctl ;).

Comment: @AdminBee so what would you reccomend using to get info on the device in order to write the rule correctly?

Comment: @rastafile so what should I do?

Comment: Actually, using `udevadm info --attribute-walk` is the correct approach to get the necessary info for writing a _udev_ rule. My first comment was only meant in case you had obtained the attribute values by some other means so that you could check with the output of `udevadm` if maybe there is some trivial typo. BTW, does `journalctl` show any _udev_ error messages when you plug in the device (which might hint at syntax errors or similar)?

Comment: @Qasim I just answered the bounty-Q, in a general way, and put a good link there. The ATTR and ATTRS "mix" could be a problem. Udev is new for me, too. With my "udevadm info" call you get a more detailed output, not that "summary"

Comment: @Qasim with `--query` it is the udev _database_ that is...queried, and you want the sysfs details. 'Tis also the only thing that made me frown (a bit, first) in your other Q, three days ago already. I hadn't realized the direct connection to /sys, and you neglect the rest a bit. That's way I put that link http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html. For both of us ;)

Comment: And now I see `-a` is nothing else than  `--attribute-walk`...I very agree now with adminbee after his second comment. What, in unix comptuting, can beat mixing up short and long options? Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

`ATTRS{model}=="USB DISK 2.0    "`

I think there is too much whitspace here. This is a string match.

Here an example from `50-default...rules`, wildcards work also:

`ENV{ID_USB_INTERFACES}=="*:0701??:*"`

Comment: After days of struggle and testing this rule I figured out why it didn't work, let's just say udev rules strictly only follow the output of udevadm info --attribute-walk. In my rule I added "ACTION="add", this wasnt specified in the output of udevadm so it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me the answer was: change your rule from `ACTION=="add"` to `ACTION=="add|change"`.